# How to use function result twice in the same select

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a stored procedure where I need to return both function results and the average from both, how can I call them only once to get the result?

```
Select 
    get_valueX(jobId, c.id), 
    get_valueY(jobId, c.id), 
    (get_valueX(jobId, c.id) + get_valueY(jobId, c.id)) / 2, 
    c.name 
From candidate c
```

(Reduced the procedure code to only required code to see the problem, also jobId is an input variable from procedure)

Comment: If the function is declared `DETERMINISTIC`, MySQL might cache the results so it doesn't call the function twice.

Comment: It's difficult to answer such a question with so less details. Can't you do SELECT a,b,(a+b)/2 FROM (SELECT get_valueX(jobId, c.id) a, get_valueY(jobId, c.id) b) FROM candidate c?

Comment: @JonasMetzler that really worked, didn't knew that it's possible to select from another select. Thanks! ☺️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select x, y, name, (x + y)/2 As xy_avg
From (
  Select 
    get_valueX(jobId, c.id) As x, 
    get_valueY(jobId, c.id) As y, 
    c.name
  From candidate c
) As t;
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks ☺️